# $\sqrt[\large m]{(x+y)}\over \sqrt[\large k]{(x+y)}$ $=\sqrt[\large m-k]{(x+y)} $?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals

Is it always true that: $\sqrt[\large m]{(x+y)}\over \sqrt[\large k]{(x+y)}$ $=\sqrt[\large m-k]{(x+y)} $ where $m,k \in \mathbb N$ ?

I tried it with a few numbers and it seems to work every time.

Comment: Can't be. The RHS is undefined for $m=k$, but the LHS is not.

Comment: It will not work if $\frac1{m}-\frac1{k} \neq \frac1{m-k}$.

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt[3]{8}}{\sqrt[2]{8}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\not=8$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be
\begin{align}
\sqrt[\large m]{x+y}\over \sqrt[\large k]{x+y}&=\frac{(x+y)^\frac{1}{m}}{(x+y)^\frac{1}{k}}\\
&=(x+y)^{\large \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{k}}\\
&=(x+y)^{\large \frac{k-m}{km}}\\
&=\sqrt[\large km]{(x+y)^{\large k-m}}
\end{align}

Comment: I just used `\large` in the `sqrt[()]` and in the exponents, to make them not so "tiny". Nice work, V-Moy!

Comment: Thank you Mr. @amWhy. I didn't know that code. I'll use it next time if I deal with the power fractions. (^ₒ^)

Comment: Don't fret about it: Your post was just fine. I've just found that how large the $n$ in an n-th root appears, and how large fractional exponents appear depends on users' screen size, browser, etc. For me, for the sake of erring on the side of larger over smaller, I've gotten in the habit of ensuring visibility. My comment was simply to explain why I edited so you wouldn't feel "off-put" by my editing your post. You did a fine job. More than anything, though, I'm glad to see your contributions: editing, posting questions, posting answers, etc. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy I didn't feel 'off-put', rather I felt honour. I am happy to learn something new that makes me so excited. ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Comment: you proved an identity, but the question is: "it is always true...". The comment of @kingW3 is an answer.